# How to create json object from dataframe column of type map(key:Int,value:struct)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

PRODUCT_ID_FETR_MAP from df is of type map(key:Int,value:struct). I want to convert that column to json object. 
DF.printschema()

```
|-- PRODUCT_ID_FETR_MAP: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_value_en: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_value_fr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_def_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_def_name_en: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_def_name_fr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_def_sortpriority: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_group_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_grp_name_en: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- feat_grp_name_fr: string (nullable = true)
```

Example -

```
 Map(0 -> [f2023,Gold,Or,Colour,Colour,couleur,null,fg2004,Hardware,Appareil], 
     1 -> [f2052,16GB,16 Go,DeviceMemory,Internal,Interne,1,fg2006,Memory,Mémoire])
```

Expected output - in json object

```
{"sortpriority":"0","FEATURE_ID":"f2023","VALUE_EN": ""Gold"","VALUE_FR": "Or",
  "DEFN_KEY":"Colour","DISPLAY_NAME_EN":"Colour",
  "DISPLAY_NAME_FR":"couleur","SORT_PRIORITY":"null",
  "feat_group_id":"fg2004","feat_grp_name_en":"Memory",
  "feat_grp_name_fr":"Mémoire" }.........
```

Can someone help me?.Thx

Answer (score 0):

For the input data:

```
case class FeaturesInfo(feat_id: String, feat_value_en: String, 
feat_value_fr: String, feat_def_key: String, 
feat_def_name_en: String,feat_def_name_fr: String, feat_def_sortPriority: 
String, feat_group_id: String,feat_grp_name_en: String, feat_grp_name_fr: 
String)

val data:Map[Int,FeaturesInfo] = Map(0 -> FeaturesInfo("f2023","Gold","Or","Colour","Colour","couleur",
                                                       "null","fg2004","Hardware","Appareil"), 
                                     1 -> FeaturesInfo("f2052","16GB","16 Go","DeviceMemory","Internal","Interne",
                                                       "1","fg2006","Memory","Mémoire"))

    //defined class FeaturesInfo
    //data: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,FeaturesInfo]


    case class jsonResult(key: Int, FEATURE_ID: String, VALUE_EN: String, VALUE_FR: String, 
    DEFN_KEY: String, DISPLAY_NAME_EN: String,DISPLAY_NAME_FR: String, 
    SORT_PRIORITY: String, feat_group_id: String, 
    feat_grp_name_en: String, feat_grp_name_fr: String)
```

Convert the input data to the below Dataset or DataFrame(Doesn't matter):

```
    val ds = data.toSeq.toDS().map(x => jsonResult(x._1,
        x._2.feat_id, x._2.feat_value_en, x._2.feat_value_fr,                                            
        x._2.feat_def_key,x._2.feat_def_name_en, 
        x._2.feat_def_name_fr, x._2.feat_def_sortPriority, 
        x._2.feat_group_id, x._2.feat_grp_name_en, x._2.feat_grp_name_fr))

    //defined class jsonResult
    //ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[jsonResult]
```

And after you successfully create the dataset/df. The result should look like below:

```
    ds.selectExpr("key","to_json(struct(*)) as value").show(false)

    |0 |{"key":0,"FEATURE_ID":"f2023","VALUE_EN":"Gold","VALUE_FR":"Or",
     "DEFN_KEY":"Colour","DISPLAY_NAME_EN":"Colour","DISPLAY_NAME_FR":"couleur",
     "SORT_PRIORITY":"null","feat_group_id":"fg2004","feat_grp_name_en":"Hardware","feat_grp_name_fr":"Appareil"}|
    |1  |{"key":1,"FEATURE_ID":"f2052","VALUE_EN":"16GB","VALUE_FR":"16Go",
      "DEFN_KEY":"DeviceMemory","DISPLAY_NAME_EN":"Internal","DISPLAY_NAME_FR":"Interne",
      "SORT_PRIORITY":"1","feat_group_id":"fg2006","feat_grp_name_en":"Memory","feat_grp_name_fr":"Mémoire"}|
```

Comment: what is data? converting this to seq.

Comment: Input data is already there in my answer. Map of String and Struct.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. in my case data( Map of String and Struct) is dataframe column. so i want to iterate data frame and create json object from that column and feed to endeca in string format. With the above approach, I am getting below exception.                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to schemas.FeaturesInfo

Comment: code I used -                                                                                       val sFetMap = row.getAs[Map[Int, FeaturesInfo]]("SKU_ID_FETR_MAP")
          .toSeq.map(x => jsonResult(x._1.toString,                  x._2.feat_id,x._2.feat_value_en, x._2.feat_value_fr,                       x._2.feat_def_key,x._2.feat_def_name_en,                         x._2.feat_def_name_fr, x._2.feat_def_sortpriority,
                          x._2.feat_group_id,                       x._2.feat_grp_name_en, x._2.feat_grp_name_fr,))
 println("sFetMap:" + sFetMap )

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you still face problems please place the code what you are trying to run and your Spark version!!